# ECS Fargate's ALB returns 503

Tags: docker, networking, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

#### The issue

1. I can access the fargate tasks individually online through their public IP. But I cannot access them through the load balancer they are configured under
2. I have an ssl.crt, ssl.key, and ssl chain attached to the load balancer currently. I haven't been prompted for another one yet, but I suspect that all this https is an issue.

   - My docker must expose on 443, which works fine when directly referenced via localhost, or ipv4.
   - Container ports on 443 with https to fargate, and my ALB listens on 443 which redirects to its DNS, but it has issues at this stage I believe.

#### What I have tried so far

My ecs deployment problems are generally summarized into

1. the container is not exposing the same port as is in the definition, this could be the case if you're deploying from a stack written by someone else.
2. the task definition memory/cpu restrictions don't grant enough space for the application and it has trouble placing (1GB, 0.5vCPU)
3. the timeout in the task definition is not set to 8 minutes (mine is set to 5)
4. the start command in the task definition does not work as expected with the container you're trying to deploy (this container doesnt use a start command)

#### The Cluster

[image: cluster]

#### The Service

[image: service]

#### The Tasks

### [image: tasks]
[image: task]
[image: tasklogs]

### Networking

#### Load Balancer

[image: lb]

#### Target Group

[image: tg]

#### Targets

[image: tgs]

#### Details

Service Event Log

1. service has reached a steady state.
2. service has reached a steady state.
3. service certified-service (deployment ecs-svc/9491895578110017561) deployment completed.

ALB Access Logs

```
h2 2021-02-07T11:44:27.671119Z app/ecr-certfied-lb/(IP)(IP).(IP):36746 - -1 -1 -1 503 - 464 635 "GET https://ecr-certfied-lb-1015030790.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com:443/ HTTP/2.0" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-southeast-2:821107282698:targetgroup/target-group-certified/(IP)"Root=1-601fd29b-66af109d70aa7fa13abd6207" "ecr-certfied-lb-(IP).ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com" "arn:aws:acm:ap-southeast-2:(IP):certificate/2977e65a-416e-4c33-b39d-(IP)" 0 2021-02-07T11:44:27.670000Z "forward" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"

h2 2021-02-07T11:44:28.304793Z app/ecr-certfied-lb/(IP)(IP).112:36746 - -1 -1 -1 503 - 146 634 "GET https://ecr-certfied-lb-1015030790.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com:443/favicon.ico HTTP/2.0" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-southeast-2:(IP):targetgroup/target-group-certified/(IP)"Root=1-601fd29c-(IP)" "ecr-certfied-lb-(IP).ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com" "arn:aws:acm:ap-southeast-2:(IP):certificate/(IP)-416e-4c33-b39d-(IP)" 0 2021-02-07T11:44:28.304000Z "forward" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: My suggestion is still to [enable the access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html) and check out the specific error codes ;-)

Comment: The only access logs that were written are testAccessLogs. None have come through since?

Comment: Access Logs at the ALB, not those inside your Containers  - these will tell you why it couldn't reach the backend ;-)

Comment: Please add them as a code block to your question, you can edit it.

Comment: Yep, just updated. Thanks, I didnt know you could edit !

Comment: Any thoughts on what could be going wrong??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228368/discussion-between-maurice-and-ventti).